# Cannot resolve symbol 'RequestQueue'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

I am new to android studio and volley library so please bear with me.

I've added volley library by GitHub and then and added this line to build gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

And now I am trying some tutorials about request and response from api, but for some reason I cannot make an instance of `RequestQueue` why?
I am using Android 4.0.3 IceCreamSandwish

Thank you

Comment: add volley as module into your project then add dependency in setting section.

Comment: I've added the module and this line is added to the dependencies in build.gradle : compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'

Answer (score 12):

add following to your build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
```

Comment: The provided link leads to ads.

Answer (score 4):

Google have added it to their own documentation pages and GitHub https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

The dependency can be added using:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this volley repo clone to your gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
```

https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley

Answer (score 2):

Add the Volley library as a dependency in the module build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.he5ed.lib:volley:android-cts-5.1_r4'
}
```

This is another mirror of the Google Volley library https://github.com/he5ed/volley

Answer (score 1):

I would add it in the build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
```

you were adding

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

which is a completely different thing (a backwards COMPATibility library for older API levels).

Comment: Add, those two are different things.

Comment: oh, cuz when i tried to add and gradle my project it comes error. but now not error hehe